# django shell < file.py import functionality

Tags: python, django, sentry

I'm trying this through a sentry command:

```
sentry --config=sentry.conf.py shell < add_user.py
```

add_user.py looks like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

try:
    import authfile
except Exception as e:
    print "authfile not present, %s" % e

def conv_dict(the_dict):
    sen_username = the_dict['sen_username']
    sen_email = the_dict['sen_email']
    sen_password = the_dict['sen_password']
    print sen_username
    return sen_username, sen_email, sen_password

for t, imp_dict in authfile.__dict__.iteritems():
    if isinstance(imp_dict, dict) and not t.startswith('_'):
        sen_username, sen_email, sen_password = conv_dict(imp_dict)
        try:
            new_user = User.objects.create_user( sen_username, sen_email, sen_password)
            new_user.is_superuser = True
            print "created new user: %s" % imp_dict['sen_username']
        except Exception as e:
            print "could not create new user: %s" % e
            pass
```

authfile is a set of dictionaries that populate the values called for in the for loop.

If I run the interactive shell and import this file, it works. If I try to pull it in with <, it runs without any output and exits, but it does not create the users like I does if I run it in the shell interactively. The output looks like this:

```
sentry --config=../sentry.conf.py shell < add_super.py
Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug  9 2012, 17:23:57)
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 1.0.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]:
In [2]:
In [2]:
In [3]:
In [3]:    ...:    ...:    ...:    ...:    ...:    ...:
In [4]:    ...:    ...:    ...:    ...:    ...:    ...:    ...:    ...:    ...:    ...:
Do you really want to exit ([y]/n)?
```

Comment: 1. try it in a normal shell and not ipython, 2. you should probably make this into a custom management command.

Comment: uninstalling ipython gives less output, but the same results. `sentry --config=../sentry.conf.py shell < add_super.py
Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug  9 2012, 17:23:57)
[GCC 4.7.1 20120720 (Red Hat 4.7.1-5)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)

>>> >>> >>> >>> >>> ... ... ... ... ... ... >>> ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...`

Comment: To your second point. Yes, I should do that. I was hoping this could be the quick and dirty solution while I got a little more familiar with django.